# Keep instance of Home Activity when launched

Tags: android, android-intent, stack, onnewintent

So, my app has 5 activities: A, B, C, D, E.  A is the splash (launcher) activity and never gets called again after launch.  After launching, B gets called and serves as the Home activity.  B, C, D, E all get called with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT so that one instance is reused and updated through onNewIntent().  It works.  I'm happy with the user experience.

Here's my question.  I would like the first instance of B (upon launch) to hold as the root task.  In other words, I would like this first instance of B to be the last screen the user sees if pressing the back button continually until exiting the app.  All other of instances of B should be "recycled" normally using the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT.

I'm pretty certain I can make a unique activity (call it B2) and accomplish this, is there a better way?

Comment: I think, you have to start all other activity except the B with using the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT. please check "https://android.jlelse.eu/android-activity-launch-mode-e0df1aa72242"

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Intent cActivity = new Intent(BActivity.this,CActivity.class);
cActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(cActivity);
```

setting `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` will hold your B Activity's instance and open your Activity C as new task. or you can call `startActivity()` without setting any flag.